# Getting ERROR: Error parsing url: undefined when trying to run migrations with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm creating a Node.js/Express.js app with Sequelize as my ORM. [This is the tutorial I'm following.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize) I'm having trouble migrating my tables onto my Azure SQL database.

My `config/config.json` file is as such:

```
{
    "development" : {
       "use_env_variable" : "DATABASE_URL",
       "dialect" : "mssql"
    }
}
```

My `.env` file is as such:

`DATABASE_URL=<connection string here>`

These are being called by this code in `models/index.js`:

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
```

I have `require('dotenv').config()` in my main file `app.js`. My understanding was that the `dotenv` package exports all of my `.env` variables throughout my project.

When I try running `node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate` in the terminal, I get

`ERROR: Error parsing url: undefined`

Why is it coming back as undefined?

Here is my file structure in case it helps.

[image]

Comment: Try saying `require(path.join(__dirname, '../config/config.json'))`?

Comment: In what file would I add this?

Comment: where you say “var config =“

Answer (score 7):

Where are you requiring your `.env` file? When you are running migration, this file would not be required and hence the error.

You should add `require('dotenv').config();` in your `config/config.js` as your first line.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this helps someone, I had this resolved by exporting the DATABASE_URL on the terminal using:

`export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://[user[:password]@][netlocation][:port][/dbname]`

As stated here: https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/45929489/use_env_variable+returned+undefined+in+sequelize

Answer (score 4):

It seem's that when you are running sequelize through cli it doesn't load your `.env` config as expected, I have the same issue and it can be resolved by creating a `.sequelizerc` in your project root folder with this content:

```js
// .sequelizerc

require('dotenv').config(); // <- require this here

// ...Any aditional configuration for sequelize-cli like custom folders for models and migrations
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('src', 'config', 'config.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('src', 'models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('src', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('src', 'migrations')
};
```

The `.sequelizerc` file would work as a configuration not just to your sequelize but also to your sequelize-cli.

Comment: this solution helped me a lot

Comment: i have same issue now, and my sequelizerc already look like that , then how to solve ? after deploying into heroku i got these problem

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this error by installing the sequelize dependency:

```sh
yarn add sequelize
```

or

```sh
npm i sequelize
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and resolved it. In my case, it is about the .env file. You need to do 2 things.
First:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

to use variables in the .env file.
Second, in the .env file, you must use the `=` to separate between key and value, like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:123456@localhost:5432/databasename
```

It took me half of a day to realize that I used the `:` in the .env file (not do this):

```
DATABASE_URL:postgres://postgres:123456@localhost:5432/databasename
```

EDIT: Just for more detail, you need to put `require('dotenv').config();` in the top of .sequelizerc file.